# Horizontal stacked bar chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to find out if there is any plugin to do a horizontal stacked bar chart with chart.js

I see there are plugins for stacked bar charts and also for horizontal bar charts, but I didn't find one that combines both.

https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.StackedBar.js

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: The question has disappeared, this question is now useful.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

UPDATED for CHARTJS V4

With the new version of ChartJS, you need to set the indexAXIS to 'y', and set the x and y scales to stacked.

```
options: {
  indexAxis: 'y',
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an updated Codepen using V4 of ChartJS
https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/vYaWyVy

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW USES ChartJS V2

I know this is a few months old, but I thought I'd add my answer for future generations.

I was able to do without extra plugins. If you set the xAxes and yAxes to stacked:true under scales, you can create a stacked horizontal graph.

```
scales: {
     xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
     }],
     yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
     }]
}
```

Here's a quick pen to show how I did it. http://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/NrROeB

Comment: Me as someone from a future generation is thankful :)

Comment: Future me here! Thank you.

Comment: Notice this won't work with latest ChartJS version 4: It triggers error ``"Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes"``

Comment: @andreszs I updated with a new sample for V4 of ChartJS.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the fork ChartNew.js (https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js). This has HorizontalStackedBars (and many other additions). See https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/050_available_graphs for how its going to look like.