# How to draw multiple color bar in a bar chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I am able to draw normal bar chart using chart.js. 
However I want to draw a bar chart as follows. 
[image: bar graph example]

I have gone through the documentation of chart.js but to no avail, also searched extensively on internet but couldn't found a single hint. Almost all the questions lead to having multiple color bars in a bar chart.

Comment: Can you please share your current code?

Comment: I am just following the code given for the bar charts in chart.js documentation. I am using chart.js for the first time. I can share the simple bar chart code given in the documentation if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, please share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieved this via `stacked` option.

```
options:{
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{stacked: true}],
    yAxes: [{stacked: true}]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer to my question. 
I wanted to have stacked bar chart.

Here is the answer.

[Horizontal stacked bar chart with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772333/horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-chart-js)

PS: I have tested the answer myself and it works perfectly fine.