# Chartjs - Horizontal Bar two values on same line

Tags: chart.js

I Need draw a horizontal bar with more then one value, like this image:

[image]

It's possible make this?

sorry my english isn't so good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal stacked bar chart with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772333/horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-chart-js)

Comment: Yes is duplicate, the solution worked