# Chart.js visualising change over time with colours

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a visual representation of the status of an object over time, and I've created something that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0vQ6.png

However, this was done by using a regular vertical bar chart using all 1s as bar data, and changing the colour of the bar based on my status data. It would make more sense to use a horizontal stacked bar chart, however the standard chart.js implementation takes arrays as input, but the data is only for one segment across multiple rows (see [Horizontal stacked bar chart with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772333/horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-chart-js), and lines 72, 76 and 80 in the accepted answer's accompanying codepen link).

If I wanted each row to have many segments (whenever the state changes, which may be many times), is there a better way to achieve this? Other libraries are acceptable, but a chart.js solution is preferred.

EDIT: Here is a code snippet to help make things a bit clearer.

```
var dataForChart = {
    datasets: [{
      data: dummyData,
      backgroundColor:colours,
      borderWidth: 0,
      xAxisId: "data"
    }],
    labels: chartLabels
};
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("statusChart"+count), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataForChart,
    options: statusChartOptions(count)
});
```

Where `dummyData` is an array of ones (so the bars appear on the graph at a fixed height), `colours` is an array of the colours of the bars, indicating status. Both of these are the length of the number of time periods (segments) I wish to capture in a day. `count` is used to loop through the code and produce one chart per day of data. Ideally I'd be able to have just one graph & I could change the y-axis labels to be the day of the week.

Comment: Can you provide some code? In what form, if not an Array are your providing your data?

Comment: I have updated the original question with some code.

To clarify, the data IS in array format. However, there is one item in the array per segment (unit of time I am measuring). This contrasts with the chart.js implementation in the link provided, where the each item in a single array is the value at one specific segment, across multiple rows (e.g. I would have hundreds of arrays of length 7, to plot hundreds of segments across a week).

Comment: yes, you shouldn't do it this way (having arrays of ones) so please provide your actual data

Comment: Actual data is an array of zeroes, ones and twos. Currently, I map these to the different colours (blue, green, and invisible). The black bars are to mark certain times & can be ignored.

Comment: please provide some of your sample data to receive help!

Comment: Apologies for the delay! My previous comment was mistaken, it's just 1s and 0s. Colour is dependent on real-world time, and doesn't directly factor into the problem. 1s are coloured, 0s are not. Some sample data is:
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]